# Is there an alternative of Wordnet similarity measure

Tags: tags, semantics, wordnet

I want to measure semantic similarity between tags. Is there an alternative of Wordnet similarity measure? Effectiveness is critical.

I read that for image crawled from Flickr is better to use Flickr distance but I didn't find enough documentation or implementation.

Comment: What are you measuring? distance between `concepts` or `words` or `images`? Flickr distance requires images as input whereas the texual language processing `concept similarity` takes texts/sentence/words/concepts as input.

Comment: i have an image dataset associated with tags crawled from Flickr
i need to search for each tag its nearest neighbors to form an hyperedge

Comment: i guess you would have to reverse-engineer from http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/W/W03/W03-0601.pdf.

Comment: Sorry may be I was unclear,my question is not how to predit words from images 
i already have for each image its associated tags 
i need to search for each tag its semantically similar tags within my dataset

Comment: 2 years have passed... Any other, and better approaches, on actual days?

Answer (score 1):

Why couldn't you use WordNet for this? If your input is words, WordNet has fairly good coverage of those, and might get you started. WordNet::Similarity (http://wn-similarity.sourceforge.net) can do a lot of this for you.

Good luck,
Ted

Comment: Wordnet is limited 
i need to measure semantic similarity between social tags